# java.lang.NullPointerException with facebook onCompleted function

Tags: java, android, facebook, nullpointerexception

i have a problem

```
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                getProfileInformation();
                informDB();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });
            }
            updateView();
        }
    }



public void getProfileInformation() {
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                    // String access_token = session.getAccessToken();

                    profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                    fbuser = new UserInfo(user.getId().toString(), user
                            .getName().toString(), null, null, null, null, null);

                    name = "dada";
                    us = user;

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Name: " + user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

            }
        }).executeAsync();
        Log.e("errorrr", us.getName());
            Log.e("errorrr", name);
    }
```

i have a function getInformation() in which i am trying to create an object UserInfo with args from GraphUser.
the problem is that the fbuser become null and i have NullPointerException

as you can see i set a variable 'name' which is string but and with this i have the same problem

Comment: is there any place which sets it to `null` which is asynchronously being called

Comment: no, for this reason i create the 'name' variable to be sure!!!

Comment: In what line you get the NPE? Have you checked the problem is not in something like `user.getName().toString()` (with getName returning null)?

Comment: i use toast inside oncompleted function and it displays without problem the facebook's name :(